# Is it possible to set up load balancing and failover simultaneously?

Tags: load-balancing, failovercluster

Suppose I have two ColdFusion servers(different machines) running the same application. Now I am bit confused between load balancing and failover techniques.
As per my knowledge,

**FailOver Cluster:** Two server will run the same application, But the second server will come into picture when the first server is down.

**Load Balancing Cluster:**  Two server will run the same application simultaneously and load will be divided between the two servers.

So in Load Balanced Cluster, if one sever fails then will it route all requests to second server ?

If YES , i think that's what failover cluster does. So what is the other benefit of failover cluster?

If NO, Can we achieve both Load balancing and HA mode simultaneously? If
yes what should be the ideal setup?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer marked `YES` is correct: in a load-balanced scenario, if one of the balanced servers goes down the balancer will stop sending requests to it, and pass them to other balanced pool servers instead.

The benefit of a simple failover cluster is for services that cannot easily be provided in a distributed manner but which you would really like not to have be unavailable (eg, NFS server, firewall).  That sort of HA is usually coupled with [STONITH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STONITH) to make sure that the other node is really, properly dead before the secondary tries to take on the function.

That sort of single-server-at-a-time HA functionality is often used for the load balancer itself (rather than the servers in the balanced pool).